# Platform independent alternatives to CloudKit

Tags: software-development

Looking for MBaas technology works like Apple 's CloudKit, but platform indepentent

- scalable
- instead of foreign keys it has back referencing
- manage blob files
- restfull api
- subscriptions
- easily managable dashboard
- cheap